# Safe Auth Lifecycle

Tags: safe-core

I'm trying to hook into the Safe Auth lifecycle to get the state of getting signed in.
There should be a variable or event to check whether the user is logged in. The Safe Auth has not provided an event to tell us that it has finished the work. (The `isAuthenticated` doesn't help because it is `false` at first and it is `false` at the end in the case of not being logged in )

Answer (score 0):

js

You could use `safeAuth.subscribe` to listen to events (including authentication), like so:

```
authPack.subscribe('accountsChanged', async (accounts) => {
    console.log('safeAuthPack:accountsChanged', accounts, authPack.isAuthenticated)
    if (authPack.isAuthenticated) {
      // do something
    } else {
      // do something else
    }
})
```

You could have this wrapped inside a `useEffect` if you are using React.

Taken from this example: https://github.com/safe-global/safe-core-sdk/blob/main/packages/auth-kit/example/src/App.tsx

Did it help answer your question? Best, Louis